# What is the "tennis ball between cylinders" trick used by flight instructors?

Tags: flight-training

From [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12205/how-do-pilots-stay-disciplined-and-use-checklists-even-after-they-have-become-r/12223#12223), "A tennis ball stuffed in between two cylinders -
a common flight instructor trick to see if students are doing a thorough preflight".

A place between the two cylinders is not the expected place for the tennis ball to be, but how does in general this "trick" work? I tried to Google but only pull out the mentioned answer.

Comment: If the student does a proper check, they will notice the tennis ball and remove it. If not, well, then the instructor has something to discuss with them.

Comment: @J.Hougaard Please post answers as answers, rather than as comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [aircraft flying handbook (page 2-9)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/airplane_handbook/media/04_afh_ch2.pdf),

> The pilot should also check for loose or foreign objects inside the cowling, such as bird nests, shop rags, and/or tools.

This tennis ball is a *tool* for instructor to see if a pilot does a proper [walkaround](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24004/before-a-flight-what-are-the-most-important-things-to-check-in-an-aircraft-wal) of the airplane. A pilot should be able to detect this strange object inside the cowling easily if he/she does the walkaround properly.